How can I use vectorization or is there another way to avoid using a for loop with numpy array?
I have a numpy array that has times in the first column and the other columns contain signal values. The objective is to use a peak finding algorithm for all the signal value columns and get the peaks and their corresponding times. My code looks like this:
import numpy as np
from peakutils import indexes

arr = stress_data.to_numpy()
times_all = arr[:,0]
peaks_all = []
width = 125

for i in range(1,np.shape(arr)[1]):
    x = arr[:,i]
    xf = x - np.mean(x)    
    threshold = 0.1*np.average(xf) / np.max(xf)
   
    # Find x-coordinates of peaks in signal
    peaks = indexes(xf, thres = threshold, min_dist = width)
        
    sg = [times_all[peaks], xf[peaks]]
    peaks_all.append(sg)

This code works as expected but the problem is that it takes a long time to run.
I tried optimizing this with the np.apply_along_axis and defining a processing function for it but doing it that way took even longer. Here is the code I used for that:
def process_column(x):
        xf = x - np.mean(x)
        threshold = 0.1 * np.average(xf) / np.min(xf)
        valleys = indexes(xf, thres=threshold, min_dist=width)
        return [times_all[valleys], xf[valleys]]

    valleys_all = np.apply_along_axis(process_column, axis=0, arr=data_all.T)

About the numpy array: Besides the time column, there are 10 columns to be processed and there are 10.8 million rows. Any help wiyh optimizing this would be appreciated
Edited to add an example of stress_data:
| | DateTime                  | FirstCol   | SecondCol   |
|-| ------------------------- | ---------- | ----------- |
|0| 2023-11-30 00:00:58.688   | -23.811199 | -463.813599 |
|1| 2023-11-30 00:00:58.696   | -23.830700 | -463.848297 |
|2| 2023-11-30 00:00:58.704   | -23.845900 | -463.867615 |
|3| 2023-11-30 00:00:58.712   | -23.852900 | -463.875397 |
|4| 2023-11-30 00:00:58.720   | -23.844101 | -463.868500 |


apply... doesn't compile process_column.  So that function has to be executed in python once for each row.  That's not a speedup approach.

xf and threshold can be calculated for all data.  But that indices function is imported, and not 'native' numpy.

indexes function is from the peakutils package and I am using it to find the "peaks" from the signal. How would I go about calculating xf and threshold for all data since the different signals have greatly differing values and thus xf and threshold are different for each column?

@hpaulj would it be more efficient to use find_peaks function from scipy signal? Is that more optimized to work with numpy arrays?

It looks like the indexes (or find_peaks ) function will take up most of the runtime, so it's probably a good idea to optimize that first. To do that, we'll need to know the exact requirements of the peak function. Note that the more you can simplify it, the easier it will be to speed up. Also, if you could provide a realistic example of stress_data, we'll be able to test it out ourselves, which is necessary for an accurate answer.

Also, if you only have 10 columns for 10 million rows, I don't think there's much benefit to avoiding the loop.

np.mean, np.max and np.average have ans axis argument wich will help you avoid for loops.

Seems like the perfect application for a numba function if you can specify the algorithm sufficiently.

@ken I added an example of stress_data to the question. The indexes function is used to find peak values from the signal with the given parameters. The function comes straight from the imported module so I don't know how I could optimize it. Also the 10 million rows is a chunk from a larger dataset (billions of rows). This peakfinding part takes up the most time in my analysis so I figured I should optimize it first.

What we need is data that can be used as benchmark input, so a few rows of samples are not enough. Note that performance can vary by several times depending on the input. So you have to prepare the data carefully. By the way, is the threshold calculation correct? Mathematically it will always be 0, and in practice it will be a small value that came mostly from rounding errors.
